# event attched to link button inside gridview is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid in asp.net, inside the asp.net i am binding data as  linkbutton when clicking on link button I need to call a method in code behind. the attached event is not woking in my code. how i can solve this?

my code is similar like this,

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
            link.Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
            link.CommandArgument = "Hello";
            link.Click += new EventHandler(this.onLinkClick);  
            e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(link);
        }

    }

    protected void onLinkClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
        string value = btn.CommandArgument;
        TextBox1.Text=value;
    }
```

Comment: 'Not working' as in 'Not firing' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the function that binds the source to the GridView everytime in the Page Load

ex.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     PopulateGridView();
}
```

Comment: grid is loading properly but the event attached to the gridview data is not firing

Comment: i know that... but when the page Post Back... the events are not attached anymore to the controls.. you have to call the functions that binds the events to the controls every post back

Comment: @niknowj what happened still not firing?

Comment: yes that was the issue. but by doing this i need to call PopulateGridView() twice. once on button click. next on page load. how i can avoid this?

Comment: @niknowj please let us know if it worked.. if calling it on OnInit event solved your problem.. we like to learn to..

Comment: -1 for band-aiding. Rebinding the grid in Page_Load or OnInit() may work, but is not a good solution.

Comment: @PhilipBadilla I called it in Page_Load, that solved my problem.

Comment: @ChrisGessler, if it is not a good solution, can you provide a better solution than just down voting.

Comment: @niknowj; I did provide a solution.  The problem with rebinding the grid during postback is performance.  Basically, you're replacing what MS just did in the background with the Viewstate that was posted. So, either remove Viewstate from the grid, or use my solution.

Comment: @niknowj; Another good solution here is the one from Massimiliano Peluso.  It's more in line with what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is not logic for adding or not the link button(I guess you have to add it for each record) why don't you add it at design time?

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        ....
    <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>            
    </ItemTemplate>
    ......
    </asp:GridView>
```

Make sure that `AutoEventWireup="true"` on the page

Comment: +1 for an alternate solution to using the built-in "<asp:ButtonField>"

Answer (score 0):

Handle `RowCommand` event of `GridView` to handle "events" of buttons and you are adding `LinkButton` dynamically then Data Binding must be performed either at `Page_Init` or `Page_Load`.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
            link.Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
            link.CommandArgument = "Hello";
            e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(link);
        }
    }

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
       string value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
       TextBox1.Text=value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook up the event handler for your dynamic button in the GridView's RowCreated event or it won't fire.  Then use "FindControl" in the RowDataBound event handler.  Personally, I don't like this model at all but sometimes it's unavoidable.

You should use the GridView's `<asp:ButtonField>` with the grid's RowCommand event.  This way, you're not the one creating the dynamic control and wiring up the events.

[Here's an article on how to use it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx)