# Postback not working on dynamically added form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

On Edit Click i am loading a form through jquery

```
<a class='txtBlue floatLeft marginRgt20' href='javascript:void(0);'
 onclick='javascript:onEditEmail(<%# Eval("DynamicEmailID")%>);'>
    <span class='tableIconset edit floatLeft'></span>Edit</a>
</a>
```

I have written following jquery to load the form

```
function onEditEmail(dynamicEmailID) {       
    var url = "AjaxControls/DynamicEmails.aspx?dynamicEmailID=" + dynamicEmailID;
    inlineControl(url);
}
```

This form is loaded but when i want to click the button

```
<asp:button id="bSave" runat="server" text="Save" onclick="bSave_Click"/>
```

on this form,its click event is not fired because the form is not postedback on click of Save Button. What can be the reason as i am using .aspx form not .ascx controls which are actually a one way pipings

Comment: see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310560/event-attched-to-link-button-inside-gridview-is-not-working hope its help you to resolved it

Comment: When you hover the `button` are you able to see something like `__doPostBack('bSave_Click','')`?

Comment: No @Murali Nop, nothing there

Comment: @ZaveedAbbasi, If nothing shown or rendered, then I dont think you can fire a code behind `bSave_click` event other than just posting a form and executing `page_load`

Comment: Working on it and hopefully will come-up with a solution, but i wonder who are the Brainless Intellectuals who just go on down-voting, although I don't care much about it

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show the resulting html of the form/button that is rendered.